# Where can I request ardor ignis testnet coins?

Tags: nxt, ardor, faucets, ignis

I can't seem to find a faucet to get ardor or ignis coins since u cannot mine it. Where can one get some?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can request Ardor Testnet coins here: https://nxtforum.org/testnet/some-testnxt-to-test-asset-exchange/